# Does anyone know how to use live persona card and load data from a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, spfx-tooling

Does anyone know how to use live persona card and load data from a SharePoint list

Answer (score 1):

For creating the persona you will require following parameter

```
    imageUrl: TestImages.personaFemale,
    imageInitials: 'AL',
    text: 'Annie Lindqvist',
    secondaryText: 'Software Engineer',
    tertiaryText: 'In a meeting',
    optionalText: 'Available at 4:00pm',
```

As you want to display the persona from SP list you are require to maintain above field in list.

- You can fetch the details from SP list using  spHttpClient or PnP JS.
- Refer bellow docs for setting up PnP JS.
- [getting-started](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/)
- Below is code for fetching the list item from SharePoint online

```
public GetAllItems(listname: string): Promise < any[] > {
  let ListItem: any[] = [];
  return new Promise<any[]>(async (reslove, reject) => {
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listname).items.select("imageUrl", "imageInitials", "text", "secondaryText", "optionalText").get().then((result: any) => {
      result.map((result: any) => (ListItem.push({ imageUrl: result.imageUrl, imageInitials: result.imageInitials, text: result.text, secondaryText: result.secondaryText, optionalText: result.optionalText })))
    })
    reslove(ListItem);
  })
}
```

- below are sample code for creating the persona.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  IPersonaProps,
  IPersonaSharedProps,
  IPersonaStyles,
  Persona,
  PersonaSize,
  PersonaPresence,
} from '@fluentui/react/lib/Persona';
import { Icon, IIconStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Icon';
import { Stack } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Stack';
import { TestImages } from '@fluentui/example-data';

const personaStyles: Partial<IPersonaStyles> = { root: { margin: '0 0 10px 0' } };
const iconStyles: Partial<IIconStyles> = { root: { marginRight: 5 } };

export const PersonaCustomRenderExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const examplePersona: IPersonaSharedProps = {
    imageUrl: TestImages.personaFemale,
    imageInitials: 'AL',
    text: 'Annie Lindqvist',
    secondaryText: 'Software Engineer',
    tertiaryText: 'In a meeting',
    optionalText: 'Available at 4:00pm',
  };

  return (
    <Stack tokens={{ childrenGap: 10 }}>
      <div>Custom icon in secondary text</div>
      <Persona
        {...examplePersona}
        size={PersonaSize.size72}
        presence={PersonaPresence.offline}
        onRenderSecondaryText={_onRenderSecondaryText}
        styles={personaStyles}
        imageAlt="Annie Lindqvist, status is offline."
      />
    </Stack>
  );
};

function _onRenderSecondaryText(props: IPersonaProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon iconName="Suitcase" styles={iconStyles} />
      {props.secondaryText}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Persona]

- For more information refer the below docs.
- [Persona](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/persona)

Comment: Well i want that persona card to get data dynamically from a SharePoint list and not only parse every person to the code .